# Get parent collection of sub-collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Consider the following code which tries to determine the parent collection of a doc:

```
  //const testRef = db.collection('dealers')
  const testRef = db.collectionGroup('stats')
  const statsTest = await testRef.get()
  statsTest.forEach((stat) => {
    console.log(stat.ref.parent.path)
  })
```

For the root collection 'dealers' the path is 'dealers' which is correct and expected.
For the sub-collection 'stats' the path is '02pw7ZM3OtUS3irhO1aF/02pw7ZM3OtUS3irhO1aF/stats' which is not what I expected. I expected the first segment to be 'projects' in this case which is the parent collection of the 'stats' sub-collection. Is this a bug in Firebase?

Comment: I thought `path` was removed from the Firebase SDKs, so am actually surprised to see it still in there. If you just keep going up the `parent` chain and print the `id` values, you should be getting back to the root collection though.

Comment: Going up the parent chain just pops path segments. So '02pw7ZM3OtUS3irhO1aF/02pw7ZM3OtUS3irhO1aF' then '02pw7ZM3OtUS3irhO1aF'. Prob is the id of the doc as the first segment instead of the parent collection name. Should be 'projects/02pw7ZM3OtUS3irhO1aF/stats'.

Comment: Did you try it in code? Afaik: you can go up the parent chain all the way to the root collection (after which `parent` will be `null`), so you should end up with `dealers` as the last (top-level) value in that chain. --- If that's not what you get, can you edit your question to show that code (and its output) too?

Comment: Kindly disregard. Turns out this was bad data on my local machine. Somehow when I edited a couple of docs in the sub-collecction, it moved them to a new parent collection with the same name as the doc id. Firefoo gremlin.